# Handling the child process starting

Tags: node.js, process, spawn

I'm using `spawn` for creating child processes. I want to create a child process and after *it is started* I want to exit the current process.

```
var Spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

var sp = Spawn("sleep", ["10000"]);        
sp.unref();                                

process.exit();
```

The code above works fine: it creates a child process (`sleep`) which will live 10 seconds and the current process is exited.

Can I be sure that when I do `process.exit()` the `sleep` process is active or by ending the parent process the child process will be killed as well?

In this is a simple example, `process.exit()` is useless since the process will end anyway because I call `unref`. However, this is just an example.

So, is there any event to listen to comming from `sp` (the child process) which tells me that *hey I'm active*?

In some cases (e.g. `var sp = Spawn("node", ["foo", "--bar"]);`) I see `[nodejs] <defunct>` in the output of `ps aux | grep node`, right after the spawn call. This happens in the debugging mode where I can control the app running. That means the process is not yet active, I guess.

Comment: Signals are your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `io.js` source, [`child_process.spawn()`](https://github.com/iojs/io.js/blob/19ffb5cf1c50e9d91d0a7a35152d20f175a2385d/lib/child_process.js#L926-L946) calls [`ChildProcess.spawn()`](https://github.com/iojs/io.js/blob/19ffb5cf1c50e9d91d0a7a35152d20f175a2385d/lib/child_process.js#L1047-L1135) which sets the `.pid` property only after all the error checking has happened. So one thing you can do is check to see if the `pid` property is set on the object returned by `spawn()` and if it is, then you can be assured that your child process successfully launched.

(It might be better to look closely at how all the errors are propagated back and handle them instead of relying on the `pid`. Or maybe `pid` is totally reliable because you can't have a `pid` without a process? Someone who knows more want to weigh in with a comment or edit this answer directly to improve it?)

If you want the child process to continue running after your code exits, you will want to set [`options.detached`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached). Otherwise, the child process will exit when the parent process exits.

`defunct` is explained in the [`ps` man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps):

> Processes marked  are dead processes (so-called "zombies") 
>   that remain because their parent has not destroyed them properly. These 
>   processes will be destroyed by init(8) if the parent process exits."

Comment: If I can check the PID of the child process immediately after running `child_process.spawn()` then does it mean that the process starting is synchronous and blocking? If the pid is set on the object returned by `spawn` and it is not set e.g. if the command is not found then spawn must be blocking while the PATH is searched, file system is accessed etc. Is that correct?